# How to take the strings from a listbox to a messagebox?

Tags: c#, winforms

Trying to create a message box with an order after someone has choses their pizza type.
I'm very new to windows forms and still not sure of the basics of transferring data across the different tools. Trying to learn for my NEA project

Here is what I tried the first two sub programs are allowing the user to change their order within the listbox and clear it.  I don't know  what to put in the final subprogram to copy the data across.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    if (radioButton1.Checked)
        listBox1.Items.Add(radioButton1.Text);
    if(radioButton2.Checked)
        listBox1.Items.Add(radioButton2.Text);
    if (checkBox1.Checked)
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox1.Text);
    if (checkBox2.Checked)
        listBox1.Items.Add(checkBox2.Text);
}

private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    listBox1.Items.Clear();
    radioButton1.Checked=false;
    radioButton2.Checked=false;
    checkBox1.Checked=false;
    checkBox2.Checked=false;
}

private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(listBox.items.text)
}
```

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Probably as simple as `string.Join(listBox1.Items)`

Comment: the main problem is that it sees listbox as a different object and wont convert to string -->Argument 1: cannot convert from 'System.Windows.Forms.ListBox.ObjectCollection' to 'string'

Comment: `MessageBox.Show(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBox1.Items.OfType<string>()));`

Comment: Just an addition to @Jimi code, If in case you wanted to use class objects as items then override the `ToString()` method in the object class and use `listBox1.Items.ToString()` instead of `listBox1.Items.OfType<string>()`

Comment: @AqibChattha But, if you can see the items' text without setting the DisplayMember Property, `ToString()` is already overridden. If you have set the DisplayMember, you just do: `listBox1.Items.OfType<object>().Select(item => listBox1.GetItemText(item))`

Comment: @Jimi Sorry my bad for not explaining properly, But since he is using orders I just wanted to give a hint in case he needed a concatenated string of multiple properties like name, qty, price, etc. as that would be more appropriate. But if it's single property then your solution is great :)

Answer (score 0):

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach (object o in listBox1.Items)
{
    sb.AppendLine(o.ToString());
}
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

You can do string concatenation, but Stringbuilder will work better.

Remember to import `System.Text` and accept my answer if it helps you:)

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Jimi's [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76947083/how-to-take-the-strings-from-a-listbox-to-a-messagebox/76947313#comment135647386_76947083) above:

In this line:

```
MessageBox.Show(listBox.items.text)
```

There are several issues.

3 of them are probably typos:

1. `listBox` should be `listBox1`.
2. `items` should be `Items`.
3. Missing `;` at the end of the line.

The last and probably main issue is of converting the `Items` into a `string`.
`Items` is a [`ListBox.ObjectCollection`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listbox.objectcollection?view=netframework-4.8) and doesn't have a `text`/`Text` property.

However, `ListBox.ObjectCollection` is derived from `IEnumarable`, and so you can use [`string.join`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.join?view=netframework-4.8), together with [`Enumerable.OfType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=netframework-4.8) from **Linq**:

```
using System.Linq;

// ...

string msg = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, listBox1.Items.OfType<string>());
MessageBox.Show(msg);
```